# why Textfield control not taking props (classes)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am trying to change my input field border when I focused to input field.currently it is showing `blue`.I want to change it to `red` or other color.

I tried using passing props

```
function Control(props) {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      InputProps={{
        inputComponent,
        inputProps: {
          className: props.selectProps.classes.input,
          inputRef: props.innerRef,
          children: props.children,
         classes:{underline: props.selectProps.classes.underlineInput,
          root: props.selectProps.classes.inputRoot,
          focused: props.selectProps.classes.focusedLabel,},

          ...props.innerProps
        }
      }}
      {...props.selectProps.textFieldProps}
    />
  );
}
```

`underline: props.selectProps.classes.underlineInput` tried to change my  input field border color.but it don't work why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/71267zp3l6

Answer (score 0):

Add this class on your CSS file. It uses `!important` for the override.

```
.MuiInput-underline-44:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #9f3063 !important;
}
```